# Passing a parameter to SqlDataAdapter results in "Must declare the scalar variable"

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqldataadapter

The method below should return ds which will be bounded to a datagridview but I am getting error message that says

> Must declare the scalar variable "@ID"

```
public DataSet GetPatientSessions() {

    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstr"].ToString();
    string cmdStr = @"SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS SEQ,
                      ID,
                      DAT,
                      S_HOUR,
                      E_HOUR,
                      KIND,
                      ENOPER,
                      ENDATETIME
                      FROM SEANCE
                      WHERE SICK_ID=@SICK_ID
                      ORDER BY ENDATETIME ASC;";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn)) {

        try {

            conn.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = cmdStr;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SICK_ID", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = Convert.ToInt32(TB_PatientID.Text);

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            //da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(ds, "PatientSessions");
            return ds;
        }

        catch (Exception ex) {
            string ErrorMsg = ex.Message.Substring(0, Math.Min(ex.Message.Length, 1024));

            return null;
        }   
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 4):

You add the parameter to your SqlCommand but then you don't associate this SqlCommand to the SqlDataAdapter. Thus, when you execute the SqlDataAdapter.Fill method your adapter has no knowledge of that parameter

You just need to use the DataAdapter's SelectCommand property or pass your command to the SqlDataAdapter constructor

```
// You can build a parameter directly with the Add method 
// using the proper overload
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(TB_PatientID.Text); 
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180551/discussion-between-steve-and-sam).

Answer (score 1):

Either pass `cmd` to `SqlDataAdapter`'s constructor as Steve suggested

Or assign `cmd` to the `SelectCommand` of the `SqlDataAdapter`:

```
conn.Open();
cmd.CommandText = cmdStr;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(/*remove cmdStr and conn from here*/);

//----
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
//----

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = Convert.ToInt32(TB_PatientID.Text);

da.Fill(ds, "dsTable1");
```

Comment: the error gone but the datagridview load with only one empty row while there are more than one row and filled with data

Comment: @sam please try to fetch and report relevant data because we don't see any datagridview and we don't use magic! what is in loaded in`ds`?

Comment: please if do not mind to take a look at my code explanation udpate

Comment: @sam I don't recommend doing this. Now the question and the code are irrelevant.

Comment: @Ok ill post new question sorry

Comment: @sam that would be better. and please revert the question to its initial state so that the future readers can understand the problem better.

Comment: done and new question posted if you can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52450515/no-data-returned-from-bounded-dataset